# Crear tabla estática con header fijo

Tags: html, css, table

Estoy intentando crear una tabla estática y con un header fijo con Html y Css. La idea sería que la tabla (que está dentro de un modal) esté fija para que el modal no sea extenso, sino que se pueda scrollear la tabla sin necesidad de scrollear el modal. Probé con scripts de Jquery como GridViewScroll y con estilos independientes pero no pude llegar a nada bien hecho y estético visualmente. Dejo por acá mi código... Cualquier ayuda es agradecida! Estoy utilizando a su vez Django, por las dudas...
Aclaración: No hay código css de la tabla "tabla_articulos_pedidos" que es a la que le quiero crear el header fijo, por eso no lo posteo, y en el HTML hay restos de las pruebas con GridViewScroll...

Html:

```
{% extends 'BASE.html' %}

{% load cart_tags %}

{% load static %}

{% block title %}
Crear pedido
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3 class="titulo_tabla" style="margin: 35px 0px 35px 0px;">Nuevo pedido</h3>
        <h5 class="objetos_inline">Cliente: </h5>
        <select class="objetos_inline">
            <option value="">Seleccione un cliente...</option>
            {% for cliente in clientes %}
                <option class="opcion">{{cliente.nombre}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <h5 class="objetos_inline" style="margin-left: 35px;">Pedido N°: {{numero_pedido}}</h5>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="div_botones_pedidos">
            <a href="#">
                <button type="button" class="btn botones_pedidos" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_articulos">
                    <img class="imgs_botones" src="{% static 'img/agregar.png' %}">
                    Agregar artículo
                </button>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <button type="button" class="btn botones_pedidos">
                    <img class="imgs_botones" src="{% static 'img/borrar.png' %}">
                    Eliminar artículo
                </button>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <table id="tabla_articulos_pedidos" class="table_hover borde-redondeado-tabla">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Código</th>
                                    <th>Descripción</th>
                                    <th>P.Venta</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                
                                    <tr data-articulo-id="1">
                                        <td width="33%">None</td>
                                        <td width="33%">FIAT 600 MODELO 1968                                                            </td>
                                        <td class="text-right" width="33%">20.000,0</td>
                                    </tr>
                                
                                    <tr data-articulo-id="8">
                                        <td width="33%">None</td>
                                        <td width="33%">FORD RANGER MODELO 1975                                                         </td>
                                        <td class="text-right" width="33%">30.000,0</td>
                                    </tr>
                                
                                    <tr data-articulo-id="3">
                                        <td width="33%">B-005-23656-2       </td>
                                        <td width="33%">BOMBA DE ACEITE CENTRÍFUGA                                                      </td>
                                        <td class="text-right" width="33%">20,0</td>
                                    </tr>
                                
                                    <tr data-articulo-id="7">
                                        <td width="33%">HIE-012             </td>
                                        <td width="33%">HIERRO DEL 12                                                                   </td>
                                        <td class="text-right" width="33%">1,0</td>
                                    </tr>
                                
                                    <tr data-articulo-id="10">
                                        <td width="33%">HIE-014             </td>
                                        <td width="33%">HIERRO DEL 14                                                                   </td>
                                        <td class="text-right" width="33%">250,0</td>
                                    </tr>
                                
                                    <tr data-articulo-id="11">
                                        <td width="33%">None</td>
                                        <td width="33%">NAFTA PREMIUM                                                                   </td>
                                        <td class="text-right" width="33%">0,0</td>
                                    </tr>
                                
                                    <tr data-articulo-id="12">
                                        <td width="33%">None</td>
                                        <td width="33%">ESCRITORIO DE PC MELAMINA                                                       </td>
                                        <td class="text-right" width="33%">3.000,0</td>
                                    </tr>
                                
                                    <tr data-articulo-id="13">
                                        <td width="33%">CH-050              </td>
                                        <td width="33%">CHECKEO GENERAL                                                                 </td>
                                        <td class="text-right" width="33%">100,0</td>
                                    </tr>
                                
                                    <tr data-articulo-id="14">
                                        <td width="33%">None</td>
                                        <td width="33%">SILLA DE ESCRITORIO                                                             </td>
                                        <td class="text-right" width="33%">1.000,0</td>
                                    </tr>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal_articulos" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header bg-info">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Agregar artículo</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h4 class="titulo_tabla">Articulos</h4>
                    <table id="tabla_articulos_pedidos" class="borde-redondeado-tabla">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="GridViewScrollHeader">
                                <th>Código</th>
                                <th>Descripción</th>
                                <th>P.Venta</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {% for articulo in articulos %}
                                <tr class="GridViewScrollItem">
                                    <td width=33%>{{articulo.codigo_de_barras}}</td>
                                    <td width=33%>{{articulo.descripcion_larga}}</td>
                                    <td class="text-right" width=33%>{{articulo.precio_venta}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    Cantidad: <input class="objeto_inline" id="cantidad_articulo" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese la cantidad...">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <img class="imgs_botones cruz" src="{% static 'img/cruz.png' %}">
                        Cerrar
                    </button>
                    <button form="form_ver_pedido" type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="boton_ver_pedido">
                        <img class="imgs_botones ojo" src="{% static 'img/tick.png' %}">
                        Agregar artículo
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#cantidad_articulo').keypress(function(e) {
                if(isNaN(this.value + String.fromCharCode(e.charCode))) 
                return false;
            }).on("cut copy paste",function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#tabla_pedidos tr").click(function() {
                $(this).siblings().removeClass("seleccionado")
                $(this).addClass("seleccionado")
                var numero_pedido = $(this).attr("data-pedido-id")
                $('#form_eliminar_pedido input[name=pedido_id]').val(numero_pedido)
                $('#form_ver_pedido input[name=pedido_id]').val(numero_pedido)
            })
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Este es el css de la tabla: (editado)

```
    #tabla_articulos_pedidos{
  position: relative;
}

#tabla_articulos_pedidos tbody{
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#tabla_articulos_pedidos tbody{
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Pon el código generado y no el código que lo genera. Así será un [mcve] y podremos ayudarte mejor. Te puedo poner una solución en HTML+CSS si quieres (sin necesidad de JS o jQuery)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro hola alvaro, disculpa no puedo entender bien lo que me decís con lo del código generado, pero si me dieras esa gran mano de hacerme un ejemplo te lo agradecería mucho

Comment: El código que has compartido es el código del servidor que genera la tabla (¿asp?) y no la tabla generada en sí. Es más fácil trabajar con el código generado porque así no tenemos que crear la tabla añadiendo datos de relleno.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro ya entendí a que te referís, disculpa ya lo corregí, gracias por la aclaración! No la pongo entera a la tabla porque tiene mas de 100 articulos y sería muy largo

Comment: Hola, que versión de bootstrap usas?

Answer (score 1):

Como ponía en los comentarios, se pueden poner las cabeceras fijas sólo con HTML y CSS, aunque es [una solución un poco *hacky*](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-and-table-headers/).

La idea es hacer que las celdas de la cabecera tengan `position: sticky` (no funciona con todo el `thead` o la fila del `thead`, debe hacerse en las celdas directamente, por eso digo que es un poco *hacky*).

```
thead th {
  position: sticky;   /* queremos que las celdas estén fijas    */
  top: 0;             /* en lo más alto de la tabla/página.     */
  background: white;  /* esto debería ser el fondo de la celda  */
  z-index: 1;         /* debe quedar encima de las otras celdas */
}
```

Aquí puedes ver un ejemplo:

```css
.contenedor-tabla {
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
}

table {
  position: relative;
}

thead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
  z-index: 1;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor-tabla">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Código</th>
        <th>Descripción</th>
        <th class="texto-alineado-der">Cantidad</th>
        <th class="texto-alineado-der">Precio Unitario</th>
        <th class="texto-alineado-der">Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>N&uacute;mero 1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>$1</td>
        <td>$1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>N&uacute;mero 2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>$2</td>
        <td>$4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>N&uacute;mero 3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>$3</td>
        <td>$9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>N&uacute;mero 4</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>$4</td>
        <td>$16</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>N&uacute;mero 5</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>$5</td>
        <td>$25</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>N&uacute;mero 6</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>$6</td>
        <td>$36</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>N&uacute;mero 7</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>$7</td>
        <td>$49</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>N&uacute;mero 8</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>$8</td>
        <td>$64</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>N&uacute;mero 9</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>$9</td>
        <td>$81</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Tu ejemplo me sirve pero falta un pequeño detalle, que la tabla tenga un alto fijo y que se scrollee solamente el cuerpo de la tabla, ya que con tu ejemplo si dejara las cabeceras como están y la tabla se scrolleara ya tendría el resultado que quiero, si no te molesta darme una mano con eso, tengo conocimientos medios de CSS como verás. Aún así muchísimas gracias por tu tiempo!!

Comment: Pon la tabla en un div, especifica el alto que quieras en el div y dale `overflow: auto`. Y ya está. He actualizado el ejemplo con eso.

Comment: Por alguna razón hace algo raro pero no queda como en el ejemplo. De todas formas, probando me di cuenta, que si al ```tbody``` le das ```display block``` y a la tabla le das un alto definido, logra algo como lo que quiero hacer, pero la tabla la estrecha al tamaño de una sola columna. Fijate si podes ver lo que quiero decir.[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irbTN.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irbTN.png)

Answer (score 0):

No se bien que versión de `bootstrap` usas en este caso esto lo implemente con la `versión 4.0`

lo que yo haría en tu caso solo seria modificar desde el código añadiéndole los valores que deseo, acá te dejo el código y te explico lo que hice.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content" style="height: 90vh;"> <!-- en esta linea le di el valor de la altura del modal en este caso te va a tomar el 90% de altura de cualquier dispositivo, con lo cual también anula el scroll del modal -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" style="overflow: auto;"> <!-- acá añado el scroll solo al campo que contiene la tabla -->
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
            <th scope="col">Handle</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">2</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">3</th>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">2</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">3</th>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">2</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">3</th>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">2</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">3</th>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">2</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">3</th>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">2</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">3</th>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">2</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">3</th>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">2</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">3</th>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">2</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">3</th>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">2</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">3</th>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">2</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">3</th>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">2</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">3</th>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: demo]

Espero ayudarte con esto, cualquier cosa me comentas, Suerte.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Hola Alvaro, lo que propones no apunta mucho a lo que intento lograr, lo que necesito es mas, dicho de forma simple, "un recuadro fijo donde adentro esté una tabla" para yo poder scrollear ese "cuadro" y no tener un modal tan largo. Muchas gracias por tu disposición y tu tiempo por cierto

Comment: de que hablas? si mi respuesta es lo que estas pidiendo.

Comment: Fijate en el comentario que hice, puse una foto de que le pasa a la tabla, en sí la tabla ya está pero hace eso que no entiendo porque y no se como solucionarlo

Comment: me parece que te estas confundiendo con la respuesta de @alvaro, esta es otra respuesta fíjate que hasta una imagen de referencia te puse!

Comment: Hola daniel, probe el ejemplo que mandaste y la se scrollea el modal en vez de scrollear la tabla, por eso decía que capaz que si me podías ayudar con el que puse yo, porque ese funciona como necesito pero toma el ancho de una celda y no queda como quiero

Comment: Prueba sacándoles el `width="33%"` a los `td`

Comment: Hola daniel, probe con eso pero no funciono, fijate que puse el css de la tabla, antes no tenia pero para que quedara asi le agregue un par de cosas, miralo a ver si algo te suena que puede ser el error